# AngularJs LimitTo in ngShow/ngIf statement

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do this:

```
ng-show="node.status | limitTo:1:1 == 1"
```

In a simple angular expression it works: `{{ node.status | limitTo:1:1 }}` =1

I can't get it to work in a ngShow or ngIf statement....

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: So my node.status is for example *C,1,0,19,064; or *S,1,0,19,064; When it's *S (on) it should show something, when it's *C (off), something else... Those are all objects in an ng-repeat –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)** works only with **`ng-repeat`**, you cannot have on **`ng-if`** or **`ng-show`**

> Creates a new array or string containing only a specified number of
>   elements. The elements are taken from either the beginning or the end
>   of the source array, string or number, as specified by the value and
>   sign (positive or negative) of limit.

alternatively you can have a function that implements your logic and call it within  **`ng-if`** or *`ng-show`*

Comment: what di you want to achieve

Comment: So my node.status is for example *C,1,0,19,064; or *S,1,0,19,064;
When it's *S (on) it should show something, when it's *C (off), something else... Those are all objects in an ng-repeat

Comment: and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to 'substring' and check on S/C and I would like to show a code block (GUI) when it's C and another block when it's S... (ngIf) I have now the whole string, but I need to do the check only on that char

Comment: you could create a function to implement the logic and call the function on ng-if or ng-show

Comment: Solved: $scope.display = function(status) {
        return status.substring(1,2)
    }; - thx!

Comment: @AlexLogist why do you prefer `substring(1,2)`? I think [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) was specifically designed to get exactly 1 char from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to get the specified character from a string and then use with
[`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)/[`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [`ngSwitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

```js
var app = angular
.module("myApp", [])
.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="node in [{status: '*C,1,0,19,064'}, {status: '*S,1,0,19,064'}] track by node.status">
  <div ng-if="node.status.charAt(1) === 'C'">This is status C</div>
  <div ng-if="node.status.charAt(1) === 'S'">This is status S</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div ng-repeat="node in [{status: '*C,1,0,19,064'}, {status: '*S,1,0,19,064'}] track by node.status"
ng-switch="node.status.charAt(1)">
  <div ng-switch-when="C">This is status C</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="S">This is status S</div>
  <div ng-switch-default>This is default status</div>
</div>


</body>
```